# How do I use #! instead of just # in Durandal URLs?

Tags: url, durandal, fragment-identifier, hashbang

By default, URLs created using Durandal's router is formatted as such:

http://example.com/#/whiskey-tango-foxtrot

However, I'd like to use #! for SEO purposes, so that the URL looks like this:

http://example.com/#!/whiskey-tango-foxtrot

For more info on what I mean, see: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Any idea how I may accomplish this with Durandal?

Comment: There is a post on google groups on a similar topic: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/durandaljs/F0TqaqYPnPw

Comment: Im about to start a project using durandal that will have to tacle the same problem. There is a new article on durandaljs.com that covers this topic:

http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Making-Durandal-Apps-SEO-Crawlable/

Comment: All the Durandal doc urls have changed and now have '.html' appended to the end. The new url for the link above is http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Making-Durandal-Apps-SEO-Crawlable.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to override the router plugin, like the function "preparerouteInfo", and others (cancelNavigation)